# Group list of objects into Map<String, Boolean> with value being true if any object in group has field set as true using Java stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

In a Java 17 project, I have a collection of objects with a String field propGroupName representing the group this object belongs to and a Boolean field propValActive representing whether this object is flagged as active internally.

I want to aggregate these objects by the string field into a Map<String, Boolean> with the key being the String field and the Boolean being false if all the booleans in the group are false and true if 1 or more of the booleans in the group are false. I have a working implementation with a simple for loop, but I want to know if there is a way to do this grouping through the Java Stream API, preferably in a way that short circuits? The goal is that I want to know of every group whether there are any objects in that group flagged as active.

I currently have this implementation which doesn't use the Streams API and doesn't short circuit:

```
public Map<String, Boolean> determineActiveGroups(
        HashMap<String, PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView> standardPvdgMap) {
    Map<String, Boolean> activeGroupsMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    for (PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView pvdgView : standardPvdgMap.values()) {
        if(pvdgView.getPropGroupOid() == null) {
            continue;
        }
        activeGroupsMap.putIfAbsent(pvdgView.getPropGroupName(), false);
        if(pvdgView.getPropValActive()) {
            activeGroupsMap.put(pvdgView.getPropGroupName(), true);
        }
    }
    return activeGroupsMap;
}
```

I have a different bit of code somewhere else that does something similar, but it retains the lists, and I managed to adapt something similar for what I need but I don't know what predicate I can use to finish it with. I assume it's going to use anyMatch, but I have no idea how to integrate it:

```
Map<String, Boolean> activeGroups = standardPvdgMap.values().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView::getPropGroupName, ???????));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupingBy is such a powerful collector :

```
public Map<String, Boolean> determineActiveGroups(Map<String, PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView> standardPvdgMap) {
    return standardPvdgMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(pvdgView -> pvdgView.getPropGroupOid() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView::getPropGroupName,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            PropertyValueDefinitionGroupView::getPropValActive,
                            Collectors.reducing(false, (a, b) -> a || b))
            ));
}
```

The trick is knowing that you can apply further collectors on the downstream. In this case I map to the flag, and then reduce the flags using the logical or.

Comment: Thanks. Does this code short-circuit? As in it will stop evaluating the rest of the Active flags in groups it finds as soon as it finds an active element?

Comment: Update: I have accepted this solution, but I decided not to use it because if I read it correctly, it iterates over the entire stream 4 separate times: once to filter, once to group, once to map and once to reduce. My original solution only iterated once over the entire list and would most likely be faster.

Comment: @Nzall The stream is not "iterated over" 4 separate times. Stream aren't like collections (although collections can be the source of a Stream).
It does not short circuit per group.

Comment: Then how does it process the collection? does it just go through the list 1 entry at a time and handle the processing (so filter and the 3 Collectors) for every entry?

Comment: @Nzall there are 2 operations on the stream; the filter, and the collector. The filter is lazy, ie it doesn't read any elements from te stream until needed. The collector is a terminal operation, ie it will start reading elements from the stream as long as more are available.
Of course the stream the collector read from is the one delivered by the filter, so when requested an element, the filter starts reading elements from its underlying stream (the one from the collection) and keep doing so until it finds one that passes its filter condition, or until none are available anymore.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: it's not doing iteration, but rather, it's reading the collection one item at a time, then filtering it, then dynamically building the response object from the elements that make it through the filter, and as such it's linear time, just like my original for loop? I think I still prefer my original method because it's easier to read, especially compared to that triple nested Collector at the end.

Comment: Doing 4 iterations is also linear time, btw. But yes going through the elements only once. 
If the nested notation bothers you, and that's not unreasonable, you can do 'extract explaining variable' or method to ease that.
Other than that, if you prefer the loops, use the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried: [Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))?

```
standardPvdgMap.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(pvdgView -> pvdgView.getPropGroupOid() != null)
        .collect(toMap(it -> it.getPropGroupName(), 
                       it -> it.getPropValActive(), 
                       (a, b) -> a || b)));
```